# Discrete derivative representation

Tags: derivatives, graphing-functions

I have a strange question about the representation of discrete function derivative. Suppose I have the following $f(x)$ [function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7U7l.jpg). If I compute its derivative, it gives me this [figure A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lh38l.jpg).
However, this representation is for me counter intuitive, I'll be rather using this representation [figure B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVbrX.jpg). This latter representation (figure B) gives me nice areas where I can clearly see the integral... Thus, I was wondering if I should use the first or the second representation as the discrete derivative of $f(x)$? I agree, it might be a strange question but this problem confuse me a lot since some people define for a given time serie that $\dot{x}=\frac{x_t-x_{t-1}}{\Delta t}$.

Comment: It's definitely the second one. How did you obtain the first one? You said that you computed it, so how did you compute it?

Comment: Basically I did $f^{'}(0)=\frac{f(1)-f(0)}{\Delta x}=\frac{1-0}{1}=1$ and then $f^{'}(1)=\frac{f(2)-f(1)}{\Delta x}=\frac{1-1}{1}=0$ is that right ?

Comment: I hope that you can see the mistake that you made yourself. Firstly, your way of calculating the derivative is not very rigorous. Remember that the derivative is a **limit**; we take the limit when $\Delta x$ goes to zero. Secondly, even though the numerical values do make sense in this context and you could, in a hand-waving way, say that $f'(0) = 1$ and $f'(1) = 0$, that still doesn't automatically create the graph in Figure A (the wrong graph). There are infinitely many ways of going from 1 to 0, so who said that it would be a straight line?

Comment: Clarification: The correct way of writing the values of the derivatives would be
$$
\lim_{x \to 0^+} f'(x) = 1 \qquad \text{and} \qquad \lim_{x \to 1^+} f'(x) = 0
$$
so **those** are actually, mathematically, rigorously, true.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it means that graph A could be the graph with the worse $\Delta x$ where $\Delta x=1$ (steps used in the $f(x)$ function) while graph B could be the one where $\Delta x$ goes to zero ? Sorry if I am not mathematically rigorous but I am trying to understand the concept behind it :)

Comment: So it sounds to me that, basically, you have taken the facts about the derivatives (which I wrote in my previous comment) and then "interpolated" the values in between. Or how else would you obtain the linear relationship in Figure A? There is no "worst $\Delta x$" because we only consider $\Delta x \to 0$. It doesn't have any other values in the proper definition of the derivative.

Comment: Great, I got it!